# Encoding issue with Scrapy (Python)

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a crawlspider with Scrapy. I need to get a specific part of the page with a Xpath :

```
item = ExplorerItem()
item['article'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='post-content']").extract()
```

Then I am using this item in pipelines.py.

But `item['article']` gives me a result in unicode:

```
`u'<div class="post-content">\n\t\t\t\t\t<h2>D\xe9signation</h2>\n<p>`
```

I need to **convert it in UTF-8**.

Comment: Why do you want to convert your text into bytes?

Comment: well UTF-8 is a type of encoding which Unicode supports.

Comment: I would only like to have 
`<div class="post-content"><h2>Désignation</h2><p>`
instead of 
`u'<div class="post-content">\n\t\t\t\t\t<h2>D\xe9signation</h2>\n<p>`

But I didn't manage to do this.

Comment: Python may keep native char as `u'\xe9'` but if you use `print(u'\xe9')` then you will see `é`. If you compare `u'\xe9' == 'é'` then you should get `True`, if you use `u'D\xe9s'.replace('é', "X")` then you get `DXs` - at least on Python 3.

Comment: Yes you are right. With a print, it works perfectly. The problem here is that I am sending this data to WordPress via XMLRPC. 
Scrapy only works with Python 2.

Comment: I said something wrong. I have the same problem with print. I still `u'\xe9'` instead of `é`.

Comment: just because something is supposed to be utf-8 doesn't mean it is. Follow my post to see normal characters and accept answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing are unicode characters when you see \xe9 \xe7. These are unicode characters. You may have some luck with this module [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) I have used it before with success, but those characters are fine I think your console just isn't set to render them. Web pages or source data doesn't always tell the truth about its encoding. Often data is a jumble of encodings. Unidecode will do its best to represent the character in ASCII.

[image]

```
from unidecode import unidecode
unidecode(u"\u5317\u4EB0")  # Note the u before the string on this line stands for unicode
```

Comment: Solve the rest of your problems by using regular expressions:
s = re.sub('\s+', '', s)
or standard library
s = s.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '')

Comment: Thank you for help. I installed the module with `pip install unicode` but then I get this error message `ImportError: No module named unidecode`. I will try to fix this.

Comment: you made the same typo in your comment you did in pip.

pip install unidecode

from unidecode import unidecode

Comment: I get `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unicode (from versions: ) .
No matching distribution found for unicode`.
I am on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/packages/0e/26/6a4295c494e381d56bba986893382b5dd5e82e2643fc72e4e49b6c99ce15/Unidecode-0.04.21.tar.gz#md5=089031ed00637d7078f33dad9d6a3c12

Unzip this and then run python setup.py install

Comment: Also you are still making the same typo. You are calling it UNICODE when it is UNIDECODE. I give up here. Accept my answer once it works.

Are you trollin? PIP INSTALL UNIDECODE (NOT UNICODE)

I tried so hard and got so far, but in the end it didnt even matter.

Comment: Thank you again for your help & sorry for the typo error. I finally installed unicode. The problem was that I used it on a list and not on a string. But it works now !

Answer (score 0):

Set `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='utf-8'` i `settings.py`

See docs here https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work here because I don't want to export the result. I need to use it in a process in pipelines.py.

Comment: @Cyd use `your_string.encode("utf-8")` to encode your string, btw, where are you storing data using pipeline? in MySQL? just set character set = utf8 and collation = utf8_general_ci and you will see correct data

Comment: I tried to to this :  
`article = response.xpath(self.myXpath).extract()
item['art'] = str(article).encode('utf-8')`
But I still get things like this `je le cuisine de diff\\xe9rentes fa\\xe7ons : gratins, soupes, tartes\\u2026 On peut vraiment faire plein de recettes diff\\xe9rentes`

I don't collect data anywhere. I am sending it to a WordPress blog.

Comment: Sending how? writing directly to database of WP?

Comment: No I am using XMLRPC.

Comment: Please run your scraper using `scrapy crawl your_spider -o output.json` and see if file `output.json` contains correct data, if yes, then you need to decode data at the receding end(XMLRPC or wherever you are receiving data)

Comment: I dit that. json file doesn't contains correct data. I still have `<h1 id=\"page-title\">D\u00e9couvrez toutes les recettes de couleur marron</h1>`

Comment: Did you try to send it with XMLRPC without any changes ? What did you get ? Did it display text incorrectly on the blog ? What you get on blog ?

Comment: You are too new to programming ... :P nevermind but you need lots of practice, ... anyway, to strip out `\n` you may need regex, also try this line `"".join(a.strip() a for response.xpath("//div[@class='post-content']/text()").extract())`

Comment: You are right, I am a newbie ... I am currently learning Python. Sorry if my question are dumb. I promise I try many many things and I read a tons of documents before asking for help :( 
My problem here is not only to strip \n. Here is a complete article for example : https://i.imgur.com/H7ZHece.png As you can see, there some problems with all words with accents.

Comment: What you are seeing are unicode characters when you see \\xe9 \\xe7. These are unicode characters. You may have some luck with this module $ pip install unidecode
I have used it before with success, but those characters are fine I think your console just isn't set to render them.  Web pages or source data doesn't always tell the truth about its encoding. Often data is a jumble of encodings.